# PasteXmlAsLinq as VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know of a port of PasteXmlAsLinq for Visual Studio 2013 or an equivalent tool for generating XElements from XML?

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PasteXmlAsLinq-fe6d0540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually VS 2013 still supports Addin style extensions. Still, it wouldn't hurt to convert this into a modern VSIX extension.